# Python: How can the following code be optimized or simplified?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, logic

I have a `df` as follows:

```
ContextID   EscAct_Curr_A   StepID
7289973 0.122100122           1
7289973 0                     2
7289973 0                     2
7289973 0.122100122           2
7289973 0.122100122           2
7289973 0.122100122           2
7289973 0.122100122           2
7289999 0.244200245           1
7289999 0.244200245           1
7289999 0.244200245           1
7289999 0.244200245           2
7289999 0.366300374           2
7289999 0.366300374           2
7289999 0.366300374           2
7290025 0.122100122           1
7290025 0.122100122           1
7290025 0.122100122           2
7290025 0                     2
7290025 0                     2
7290025 0.122100122           2
```

What I want to do is to club all the values from different StepIDs and create a separate df of it.

For instance, all the values of `StepID` 1 must be saved to one df, say s1 and all the values of `StepID` 2 must be saved to one df, say s2 so on. I have 24 such StepIDs.
After this is done, I want to plot a scatterplot after running a machine learning algorithm.

**What I have done:**

**For StepID 1**

```
s1 = X.loc[X['StepID'] == 1]
s1_array = s1.iloc[:,1].values.astype(float).reshape(-1,1)
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaled_array_s1 = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(s1_array)
s1.iloc[:,1]=scaled_array_s1

ocsvm = OneClassSVM(nu = 0.1, kernel = 'rbf', gamma = 'scale')
s1['y_ocsvm1'] = ocsvm.fit_predict(s1.values[:,[1]])
```

**For StepID 2**

```
s2 = X.loc[X['StepID'] == 2]
s2_array = s2.iloc[:,1].values.astype(float).reshape(-1,1)
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaled_array_s2 = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(s2_array)
s2.iloc[:,1]=scaled_array_s2

ocsvm = OneClassSVM(nu = 0.1, kernel = 'rbf', gamma = 'scale')
s2['y_ocsvm2'] = ocsvm.fit_predict(s2.values[:,[1]])
```

**Plotting the scatter plot:**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(s1.values[s1['y_ocsvm1'] == 1, 2], s1.values[s1['y_ocsvm1'] == 1, 1], c = 'green', label = 'Normal')
ax.scatter(s1.values[s1['y_ocsvm1'] == -1, 2], s1.values[s1['y_ocsvm1'] == -1, 1], c = 'red', label = 'Outlier')
ax.scatter(s2.values[s2['y_ocsvm2'] == 1, 2], s2.values[s2['y_ocsvm2'] == 1, 1], c = 'green')
ax.scatter(s2.values[s2['y_ocsvm2'] == -1, 2], s2.values[s2['y_ocsvm2'] == -1, 1], c = 'red')
plt.legend()
```

These codes do exactly what I want it to, but writing codes like this for 24 different StepIDs is a lot tedious. So, I would like to know if there's a more compact way to achieve the following, maybe by using a loop or functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 95% repetitative code. The only thing that is really different - particular step IDs. So you can use this function and call it many times with different IDs:

```
def waka(step_id, X=X)
    s = X.loc[X['StepID'] == step_id]
    s_array = s.iloc[:,1].values.astype(float).reshape(-1,1)
    min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    scaled_array_s = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(s_array)
    s.iloc[:,1] = scaled_array_s
    ocsvm = OneClassSVM(nu = 0.1, kernel = 'rbf', gamma = 'scale')

    return ocsvm.fit_predict(s.values[:,[1]])
    # OR!
    s['y_ocsvm'] = ocsvm.fit_predict(s.values[:,[1]])
    return s
```

You can store results in some kind of list or dict to draw them later.

Comment: This reduces some effort. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a possibility for the scatterplot code to get simplified as such?

Comment: You can create lists of colors and labels and then `scatter` ing inside a `for i, s in enumerate(your_list_with_result_data):`